# oracle order by missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the maximum number of distinct employees
So my code is like:

```
select ProjName from Project where ProjId in (
select ProjId from EmpProject 
order by count(ProjId) desc
group by ProjId
where rownum<=1
);
```

But it throw an error says missing right parenthesis. 
So could anyone told me how to fix this?

Comment: Your subquery has many syntax errors.  Your attemped query bears little resemblance to an attempt to count employees.

Comment: To "find the maximum number of distinct employees" does not make sense in isolation. You mean something like, find the something that has the maximum number of distinct employees. Please explain yourself.

Comment: The importance of ***indentation*** and ***code formatting***. Right now I can't tell what your _intention_ was because you didn't indent your sub-query. You're clearly unfamiliar with the sequencing rules for the clauses of a SELECT statement. So your right parenthesis _might be_ where you intended it; in which case your sub-query is incorrect. You're getting an error because GROUP BY cannot follow ORDER BY. So you need a right parenthesis before that. (Of course then your query still won't compile.) _At least make the effort to format your query so that it makes your intention clear._

Comment: The description "*maximum number of distinct employees*" does seem to match the query you have. Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Do you need to return the project as well, or just the maximum number of employees? If you need to return the projectID, what is the required output when there are two or more projects with the same number of distinct employees, and that number is maximum among all projects? Do you want one, random projectID from the ones with the max number of employees, or do you want to know **all** those project ID's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax there. The `order by` clause comes at the end and `where` comes before `group by`. So your query becomes:

```
SELECT ProjName
FROM Project
WHERE ProjId IN
  (SELECT ProjId
  FROM EmpProject
  WHERE rownum<=1
  GROUP BY ProjId
  ORDER BY COUNT(ProjId) DESC
  );
```

The above isn't probably what you want, assuming you want to get top projId with max count.

In 11g or before, you can use ordering in subquery and then apply the rownum filter outside:

```
SELECT ProjName
FROM Project
WHERE ProjId IN
  (SELECT ProjId
  FROM
    (SELECT ProjId FROM EmpProject GROUP BY ProjId ORDER BY COUNT(ProjId) DESC
    )
  WHERE rownum<=1
  );
```

In 12c and above, You can use `FETCH FIRST` like this:

```
SELECT ProjName
FROM Project
WHERE ProjId IN
  (SELECT ProjId FROM EmpProject GROUP BY ProjId ORDER BY COUNT(ProjId) DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 row only
  );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It really helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the project with the highest number of employees assigned to it, you could also use a combination of window functions and aggregation. That will work with anything since Oracle 10 (probably even Oracle 9)

```
select p.projname
from project p
  join (
    select projid, 
           row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
    from empproject
    group by projid
  ) t on t.projid = p.projid and t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()` - if two or more projects have the maximum number of employees, that will return all the projects with that (max) number of employees, not just one random one among them.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement just says "maximum number of distinct employees" - it doesn't say anything about returning the projectID of the project with the max number of employees. This means the query should just return a number, nothing else.

Assuming your EmpProject shows empID and projID for which employees are assigned to which project, and also assuming there may be duplicates (not clear why there would be, but you ask for DISTINCT employees as if there can be duplicates) - you could do something like this. Using the standard EMP table in the SCOTT schema for illustration, since you didn't provide test data; replace the table and column names with EmpProject and empID and projID to use it on your table.

```
select   max( count(distinct empno) ) as max_employees
from     emp
group by deptno
;

MAX_EMPLOYEES
-------------
6
```